# What is the meaning of 么?

Tags: characters, meaning

If you want to say "This dog," you'd say, "这只狗". If you want to say "This thing," you'd say, "这个东西". If you want to say, "This much," you'd say, "这么多".

I understand the reasons for the 只 and the 个, but what does the 么 really mean?

Comment: 么 is just a suffix here, like in 什么, 多么, 怎么.

Comment: Right...but what does that suffix mean? Does it have a meaning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

么 has lost most of its lexical meaning in modern usage, but it appears to have originally been derived from the word 物, meaning 'thing'. [*Chinese* by Jerry Norman, pp. 119-20](https://books.google.com/books?id=wOPArZVCk-wC&ots=pqrkaAWm6z&pg=PA119#v=onepage&f=false) makes mention of the etymology of various modern words featuring 么:

> In an insightful article, Zhāng Hùiyīng (1982) has shown that *shénme* 什么, the standard modern word for 'what', comes from *shí wù* 什物 (MC *źjəp mjuət*). This form (in a number of different phonological shapes) makes its first appearance in the Tang dynasty. *Shí wù* 什物 originally meant 'vessels, household utensils, things (of various sorts)'. The development of a interrogative meaning 'what' from a meaning 'thing' finds a parallel in modern Italian, where *cosa* 'thing' is also used to mean 'what'. ...
>
> ...
>
> [Regarding 'how'...] In the late Tang and Wudai periods, a different form begins to be found; it consists of the verb *zuò* 作 (MC *tsuo-*) plus one of several variants of the morpheme meaning 'thing, what' discussed in relation to the origins of modern *shénme* 什么 ... In the Wudai period, a fusion word *zěn* 怎 (from an earlier **zěm*) based on these forms appears for the first time. It is this fusion form that is directly ancestral to the modern *zěnme* 怎么 'how'. *Zhème* 这么 'in this way' and *nàme* 那么 'in that way' were probably analogically based on this form.

Notes:

- The article by Zhāng Hùiyīng 张惠英 referenced in that excerpt refers to an article entitled 释「什么」in《中国语文》1982年第4期, pp. 302-5. I wasn't easily able to obtain a copy of that article though.
- MC in that excerpt refers to how the words were pronounced in [Middle Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_Chinese) (ca. 600-1000 AD).

While it's interesting that 么 in these words was derived from a word meaning 'thing', it's essentially a [bound morpheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bound_morpheme) that is no longer [productive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Productivity_(linguistics)) and can't be used on its own. In effect, its modern usage doesn't have any particular meaning in practice. In many ways, it could be considered a [cranberry morpheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranberry_morpheme).

Comment: is there a reason 惠's pinyin is written with the accent on the u above and not on the i? Or just a typo?

Comment: @user3306356 Good catch! That's the way it was written in the source and I hadn't even notice it when I copied the excerpt. It probably is a typo.

Answer (score 1):

In 这么多 it can mean a very generic measuring "much" with 多 meaning a counting "numerous" (for counting countable and uncountable things). So you are really saying:

How (much) numerous?

Answer (score 0):

么 means ”small”, and is cognate to 幺 (yāo: one, insignificant). The full confusion will be understood by how 麽 and 麼 are used in Taiwan and the mainland.

Answer (score -1):

Agree to Drunken Master, just a suffix here.
怎～。这～。多～。什～。

It has no meaning, just sounds better.
I think "so much" is closer to "这么多".